# sqlite3 alter command delete my db

Tags: iphone, database, ipad, sqlite, alter-table

In the begininng of my app, i am running a sqlite3 command on existing sqlite3 DB.
The command goes like that:

```
    sqlStmt = "ALTER TABLE projects ADD COLUMN guid integer DEFAULT 0";
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlStmt, -1, &compiledStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
    sqlite3_step(compiledStmt);
}
```

what happens is that all my data is lost, and a "journal" file is showing (and never deleted).
I don't what to do - i understand it has something to do with transactions and locking.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal behavior since Sqlite doesn't support complex operations.
Please, [refer to the documentation.](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11)

So, all you have to do is :

1. Create a temporary table.
2. Put all the data in it.
3. Drop the initial table.
4. Create a table with the new field.
5. Send data from the temporary table to the new table

If you want more help, give us your table structure.